# jquery autocomplete - capture when the value types not in the suggestions list

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to be able to capture when the user types in a value that is not in the suggestions list.

html

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name1" />
```

js

```
$("#name1").autocomplete({
                   source: listOfNames                  
               });
```

so if the `listOfNames` is

```
['Jenny', 'Vanny', 'George']
```

and the user is typing Jennifer, I need to capture it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling the keyup event should do the trick

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/0ek1bgv5/

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(e){
    $("#output").html($(this).val());
}).autocomplete({source:listOfNames});
```

Comment: thanks, Question - pardon me if I am silly but where does this kind of output comes from "1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate." it's is nowhere in your code ...

Comment: This was beacuse I didn't include the jqueryui's css. I've updated it so now you should see the list and no message. The message is added by jquery ui